# How to allow partial string searches with elasticsearch php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to get elasticsearch to allow me to search on partial strings using the [php client library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

I have a script like this

```
// create an index
$params = array();
$params['body']  = array('testField' => 'abc');
$params['index'] = 'my_index';
$params['type']  = 'my_type';
$params['id']    = 'my_id';
$ret = $client->index($params);

// search for that index
$searchParams['index'] = 'my_index';
$searchParams['type']  = 'my_type';
$searchParams['body']['query']['match']['testField'] = 'abc';
$queryResponse = $client->search($searchParams); // contains the indexed `abc` testField
```

This works, and I am able to find the thing that I just created.

HOWEVER, when I replace

`$searchParams['body']['query']['match']['testField'] = 'abc';`

with

`$searchParams['body']['query']['match']['testField'] = 'a';`

or

`$searchParams['body']['query']['match']['testField'] = 'a*';`

The search returns zero results.

Is there some configuration that I need to set to allow partial string searching?

Comment: You need to look into ngrams. I don't know how to set it up with PHP, but here's a blog post I wrote up about ngrams (spoiler: look at the last section to get started): http://blog.qbox.io/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

Comment: excellent read! thanks! ngrams are definitely what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this while working through a separate stackoverflow question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495044/how-to-search-elasticsearch-case-insensitive/29495485#29495485). The working script is there.

Thanks to @sloan-ahrens for giving me direction on this